# How do I read and write from an external process in Java?

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I want to run PianoBar from a Java GUI (PianoBar is a program that runs Pandora from command line). I thought this would be quick and dirty, but I guess I don't know enough about interaction between programs.

I use ProcessBuilder to launch an instance of PianoBar like so:

```
    private Process createPianoBarProcess() throws IOException {
        String[] command = {"CMD", "/C", "pianobar"};
        ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder( command );
        probuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        probuilder.directory(new File("~~location where pianobar.exe is~~"));
        Process process = probuilder.start();
        return process;
    }
```

After I create the process, I create a BufferedReader to read in the PianoBar output:

```
    Process pianoBar = createPianoBarProcess();

    InputStream inS = pianoBar.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inS);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

But when I read the output from PianoBar via this reader, it spits out the first line of PianoBar ("Welcome to pianobar (2013.05.19-win32)! Press ? for a list of commands."), then it spits out the next line ("[?] Email:"). Then it just hangs.

Obviously, it is waiting for the user to input their email. But no matter what I try, I can't get my Java program to write the email to the PianoBar process when prompted - it just hangs as soon as it reads out the last character.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do? I thought it would be an easy thing to look for on the internet, but I haven't been able to find anything. All I want is an easy way to write to the external process when prompted. Seems like this should be easy...

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code snippet to get working:

```
String s;
//s = email
BufferedWriter bufferedwriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(pianoBar.getOutputStream()));
bufferedwriter.write(s);
bufferedwriter.flush();
```

Done!
Remember to surround the code block with appropriate try/catch

Comment: So this code is better than what I was using for writing, but the problem is that now after I write the email, as soon as I try to read in the next line (which should be "[?] password:"), it hangs. When I try using debug mode to look at what chars are in the BufferedReader's buffer, it just shows the chars it has read and then a bunch of empty slots in the buffer. Once it tries to read two of those empty slots, it hangs without any exceptions thrown. The buffer also shows no sign of "[?] password:".

Comment: you can enter the password in the same string with a '\n' separating the email from password.

Comment: Even trying that, the BufferedReader still hangs as soon as I try to use it again. It is as if there is something in the buffer that it can't get over. With that in mind, maybe if I could flush the buffer? But there is no way to do that it seems, and if I close the reader, I can't open it again without throwing an IOException.